# How to specify pytorch / cuda version in pipenv

Tags: pytorch, pipenv

I am trying to install a specific version of pytorch that is compatible with a specific cuda driver version with pipenv. The [pytorch website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) shows how to to this with pip:

```
pip3 install torch==1.3.1+cu92 torchvision==0.4.2+cu92 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

I tried to convert this into an entry in my `Pipfile` like this:

```
[[source]]
name = "pytorch"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html"
verify_ssl = false

pytorch = {version="==1.3.1+cu92", index="pytorch"}
torchvision = {version="==0.4.2+cu92", index="pytorch"}
```

However, this does not work. The dependency with this version can not be resolved. I am not sure if the url that is listed with the `-f` parameter in the `pip3` command is even a valid source for `pipenv`.

I could install both libraries by just passing the command through to pip like this:

```
pipenv run pip install torch==1.3.1+cu92 torchvision==0.4.2+cu92 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

but I am not really satisfied with that solution since the dependencies are not in the `Pipfile` and I have to manually document the usage of this command.

Comment: this could be used to create a workaround: https://github.com/pmeier/pytorch_wheel_installer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with the approach above lies in the structure of `https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`. Pipenv can only find torch versions 0.1 to 0.4.1 because all others have the cuda (or cpu) version as a prefix e.g. `cu92/torch-0.4.1-cp27-cp27m-linux_x86_64.whl`.

But the cuda version is a subdirectory. So if you change the url of the source to the cuda version and only specify the torch version in the dependencies it works.

```
[[source]]
name = "pytorch"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu92"
verify_ssl = false

[packages]
torch = {index = "pytorch",version = "==1.4.0"}
```

The only problem I encountered is that numpy is not recognized as a dependency of pytoch 1.4.0. But this seems to be a problem of the specific pytorch wheel. With version 1.3.1 or 1.5.1 and a recent pipenv version it works.

So if after the installation with `pipenv install`, the command `pipenv run python -c "import torch"` throws an error, numpy must be added manually.

Comment: Although this is a nice find, it seems it is not the full solution since its dependencies (here numpy) are not correctly installed. Any idea why and maybe a solution for that?

Comment: This could be either a problem of the(or some) pytorch wheels not containing the dependency (e.g. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1755), which should be fixed. Or could be a problem of pipenv, the docs say "Dependencies of wheels provided in a Pipfile will not be captured by $ pipenv lock." (https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html). However the docs do not seem to be up to date: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4231. Trying an updated pipenv and several pytorch versions should resolve who is to blame here.

Comment: With pipenv version 2020.6.2, torch 1.5.1 and on linux it works without problems and numpy is added to the Pipfile.lock

Answer (score 0):

### Solved: This is how to install Torch CORRECTLY in Pipenv. Most people do this incorrectly even in various "solutions" I've seen from other people... I've researched to the bottom of this problem and found out the real, intended solution that everyone should use.

**This technique is the correct one and it's documented here in the pipenv repository:**

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4961#issuecomment-1045679643

Comment: While it's good to include a link to the relevant information, it's helpful to also include the relevant portion in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I've just run into this issue *right now*. Take whichever URL the Torch website tells you to use and do this:

```
pipenv install torch --index https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113
```

Of course, replace `https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113` with the URL indicated for you by Torch. This updates the Pipfile correctly and worked in my system. Installed pytorch and enabled correct CUDA support.